# Application version comparison with Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch index that contains application documents. Each document has application version and some other fields:

version: 2.3.4,
name: Spotify

version: 1.2.3,
name: Sudoku

How to apply GT(greater than) search by version or customize it in this case?
If applications have 1.2.3 and 1.3.2 versions - it works fine using standard queries (GT 1 will return both documents), but in case of 1.2.3 and 2.1.3 ES returns only 1.2.3 version of the application.

Query:

```
"bool" : {
                  "should" : [
                    {
                      "range" : {
                        "application_version" : {
                          "from" : "1.2.3",
                          "to" : null,
                          "include_lower" : false,
                          "include_upper" : true,
                          "boost" : 1.0
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
```

application_version type: keyword

Comment: Show your query. Field version is keyword type?

Comment: @rabbitbr Added the query and a type in original question.

Comment: I did some tests with the range query and it worked. Maybe your problem is other clauses besides the range. I'm using ES8.4

Comment: @rabbitbr lt(lower than) case doesn't work. Example: { "application_version" : { "from" : null, "to" : "2", "include_lower" : true, "include_upper" : false, "boost" : 1.0 } returns applications with versions "13.0" and "14.0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been researching and I believe the best option for you is to change the type of application_version to [Version field type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/version.html).

> The version field type is a specialization of the keyword field for
> handling software version values and to support specialized precedence
> rules for them. Precedence is defined following the rules outlined by
> Semantic Versioning, which for example means that major, minor and
> patch version parts are sorted numerically (i.e. "2.1.0" < "2.4.1" <
> "2.11.2") and pre-release versions are sorted before release versions
> (i.e. "1.0.0-alpha" < "1.0.0").

Comment: Thanks a lot! Don't have enough reputation to mark your answer as useful, sorry for that :)

Comment: ES version is 6.8 in our environment. The version type is not available in 6.8 :(